# why i cant put inside an array all the characters i need?

Tags: ruby

i made a program and i need to put all the possible characters in an array.
here i create my variable just to read the name

```
print "write your name: "
name1 = gets.chomp
```

then i try to put all the character inside the array, for example if your name is John, the array would be: J,Jo,Joh,john

```
arrayNames = []
number = name1.length
number.times {|i| 
    arrayNames[i] = name1.slice(0,i)
}
arrayNames << name1
```

then to read it, i wanted to make a permutation program, i write:

```
numb = name1.length+ 1
numb2 = anotherVariable.length + 1
numb.times {|j|
    numb2.times {|k|
        perm = [arrayNames[j],theSecondArray[k]]
        p perm
        file1.puts
    }
}
```

of course i had the file1 made, and i have the exactly same code for the second array than the `arrayNames`but is not working. it doesnt even show an error. ill put all the code together down below

```
class Data
    def initialize
    end
    def dataIn
        print "write your name: "
        $name = gets.chomp
        print "write your surname: "
        $surname = gets.chomp
    end
    def dataName
        $passwordName = []
        numb =  $name.length
        numb.times {|i|
            $passwordName[i] = $name.slice(0,i)
        $passwordName << $name
    end
    def dataSurn
        $passwordSur = []
        numb = $surname.length
        numb.times {|i|
            $passwordSur[i] = $surname.slice(0,i)
        }
        $passwordSur << $surname
    end 
    def alg1
        numb = $name.length + 1
        numb2 = $surname.length + 1
        numb.times {|i|
            numb2.times {|j|
                perm = [$passwordName[i], $passwordSur[j]].permutation.map {|k| 
                k.join} 
                p perm
                $archivos.puts perm                 
            }
        }
    end
end
```

the code itself is a little bit more complicaded, but my question is the same. the method alg1 doesnt work.then i just call them and create the file

```
data = Data.new()
datos.dataIn
$archivos = File.new("passwords",'w+')
File.open("passwords")
data.datosName
data.datosSurn
data.alg1
gets()
```

Comment: Have you run the commands line by line in the ruby shell?  What do you see as the value of arrayNames (or numb) in the process?  Also the term for the value of slice(0, i) is 'prefix'

Comment: yes i did. the slice(0,i) worked when i put it alone and the array name shows what i said before, the example with John

Comment: the last part is what doesnt work, the third one

Comment: You can run code inside the block with different values of j and k to see what happens. Given that "theSecondArray" is undefined, that might be part of the problem.

Comment: hello, could you add more code - it's not clear what are `theSecondArray` and `anotherVariable`. Are you sure it should be `arrayNumber << name1 ` and not `arrayNames << name1`?

Comment: yes it is arrayNames, i was going to put all the code but i did that before and people said that´s not the kind of things we should ask here. ill edit it and lets see if i can explain myself better so you understand

Comment: The `$` prefix in Ruby means *global variable* and that's not something you should do without serious consideration. I think you mean to use `@` here which means *instance variable* and is unique to the instance of `Data`. Right now every instance of `Data` is using exactly the same variables, which is probably broken.

Comment: Another thing to note is Ruby strongly recommends naming variables and methods all lower-case, so `passwordSur` should be `password_sur` and so forth. Capitali letters have significant meaning in Ruby.

Comment: ill change that and ill see if it works. i thought the capitali letters only affected if its in capitalized the first one, but ill change it too, just to get used to it, thank you

Comment: it didnt work. It´s still doing nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but Ruby's built-in Array methods will make your life much easier:

```
>> name1 = 'John'
=> "John"
>> names = (0...name1.length).map { |i| name1[0..i] }
=> ["J", "Jo", "Joh", "John"]
>> other = ['dog', 'wolf', 'sheep']
=> ["dog", "wolf", "sheep"]
>> result = names.product(other)
=> [["J", "dog"],
 ["J", "wolf"],
 ["J", "sheep"],
 ["Jo", "dog"],
 ["Jo", "wolf"],
 ["Jo", "sheep"],
 ["Joh", "dog"],
 ["Joh", "wolf"],
 ["Joh", "sheep"],
 ["John", "dog"],
 ["John", "wolf"],
 ["John", "sheep"]]
```